# Onboarding HQ requires 1 week to stay in an expensive city

Tags: interviewing, hiring, training, onboarding

Got a new Job as manager in a startup company. They invited me to do the onboard training in their HQ which is in Paris. I have to stay for 7 working days.

Should I expect them to give me extra money for the days? Apart from the hotel and travel expenses?

Comment: "extra money" for what? often food is included if you're away from home, but your own touring happens with your own money.

Comment: What exactly is expensive about the city that the company has stated you are responsible for?

Comment: Are you asking about a per-diem? I wouldn't say 'extra icecream is pricey in Paris,' I'd say everything is Paris is expensive. Paris is a very expensive city. If they're not providing food, they should give you a per-diem. And they should be paying for your hotel room.

Comment: You will need to check with the company, but normally you should have all the necessities (food, accomodation, and travel) paid for - so long as it is reasonable. If you go out at a high-end restaurant and order lobster and champagne every night, expect it to get bounced back.

Comment: Expect nothing. Ask the company.

Comment: @Mast expect what you're legally entitled to, which is highly unlikely to be nothing.

Comment: Just make sure you don't fly Air Zalagasa when you take your trip.

Comment: @CrashGordon I had to Google that...

Comment: "**Should I expect them to give me extra money for the days? Apart from the hotel and travel expenses?**" Do you mean that the company should pay you extra because of the hardship that you suffer while traveling to and staying in Paris  (maybe, because the hardship from travel is a lot more than the regular work you do at the normal office) ?

Answer (score 77):

My expectation would be that such a trip would be covered under the company's standard travel policy.  You would be wise to ask about it and follow their guidelines.

In some cases it involves booking travel reservations via the company's travel agent.  But asking about things such as incidentals and meals is certainly fair-game.

Not all companies have the same travel policies so you should ask.

Comment: The question specifically mentions "startup". Depending on how old it is, there's little to no chance of it having a "standard travel policy" yet.

Comment: @MSalters Right, but they may well be required by law to cover travel expenses on business trips. I'm not familiar with French labour law at all, but at least that's the way it works in all EU countries that I worked in.

Comment: @TooTea: Too be fair, the one time I worked in Paris and sent in my expenses, they were more offended by the 10 Euro bill from McDonalds than the 100 euro bill from a proper French restaurant!

Comment: @TooTea You can assume that it will be VERY favorable to the employee.
I'm not really up to date but last time i checked they have to pay for everything related to your travel, so hotel, evening meal, probably the noon meal, metro if necessary to go to work.

Best of luck with your onboarding.

Answer (score 40):

I don't know where you live or what the norms are there. I am answering with what I as a Brit perceive the norms are. I'm pretty sure it's similar for Americans, in the rest of the world I have no idea.

Assuming it's a salaried position I would not expect extra pay as-such for travel. I don't know how it works for hourly workers.

You are travelling for your employer's benefit, not your personal benefit. As such, I would expect your employer to pay for things reasonably necessary to complete the trip. I would expect that to include:

- Your hotel accommodation for days the employer expects you to be there.
- Your flights to/from Paris.
- Local transport between airport, hotel, HQ etc.
- Some form of provision for food/drink, recognising the fact that food while travelling is generally significantly more expensive than food at home (even if the place you are travelling to is of similar wealth-level to where you live). Some companies may be more generous than others on what exactly is included in this, and some may offer a fixed "per diem" payment as a substitute for actual expenses.
- Travel insurance; your employer may already have a blanket policy covering business travel for all employees, but you should check the details before travelling.

I would not expect it to include:

- Entertainment/leisure activities.
- Extra food/accommodation costs if you choose to extend the stay for leisure reasons.
- Local travel not related to work/accommodation.

Comment: As a salaried Brit, I would expect travel for a work-related gig to be on work time (or even double-time if travel was necessary on Sunday to start on Monday).

Comment: @AndrewLeach I wouldn't be confident of this being the case in a startup

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'd expect time off in lieu for weekend travel (probably at 1 day per day spent travelling, but watch out for mean definitions of "day" where you lose the ability to do anything on a weekend day but get 1/2 day back in lieu)

Comment: Per diem allowances are unknown in some fields in the UK, partly because of the tax hassles; when they do appear it's often for sales staff.  Receipted expenses with a daily limit are very common, and sometimes quite tight.  Also note policies on what you can include as a meal especially if you like alcohol - one drink with dinner may be acceptable, probably no more (a former colleague got away with interpreting that as a bottle of wine and a sandwich but it's not good to push it)

Comment: Who in their right mind will do any of these; *Entertainment/leisure activities.
Extra food/accommodation costs if you choose to extend the stay for leisure reasons.
Local travel not related to work/accommodation.* in the job?

Comment: @NotStandingwithGoGotaHome if the company is paying for your tickets to get somewhere worth visiting, for a full week, why not make use of the weekend to see Paris for the cost of an extra night's accommodation?

Comment: @ChrisH Interesting. In Canada we can use the per diem rates that Federal employees get, which are specified by country and even by city in some cases. For example, in Paris a per diem of  €180.31 is allowed for meals + incidentals up to 30 days.  Breakfast/Lunch/Dinner at €28/€49.25/€59.35 and incidentals at €43.71. France outside Paris is €144.25 per day. April 2022 rates.

Comment: Of course not all companies will offer per diem or as much as that, but if you stay at or below those numbers there is no issue with taxes.

Comment: @ChrisH who said you can burn *cost of an extra night's accommodation* on your will? Does the employer pay for one week and this guy travels for like 4 days? if so - why the heck did the company book the hotel longer than actually needed? btw this was a rhetorical question. After all who would do that was my comment, not why. :)

Comment: @NotStandingwithGoGotaHome no one said anything about booking too long. A fairly typical example is the company wants you to fly out on Sunday p.m. ready for Monday a.m.  Flights on Saturday a.m. are the same price, so the company will pay.  For the price of a hotel room (and meals)  out of your own pocket you can get a weekend in Paris. You may have to change rooms to be on a separate booking; you may choose to change hotels.  Obviously you might lack the money or the time, and then you wouldn't do it.

Comment: @ChrisH it was rhetorical, I was challenging the probability of someone thinking he can spend money off the work accounts. :)

Comment: @NotStandingwithGoGotaHome well I'm not sure why you're challenging me about that because I didn't suggest it

Comment: ... It could even work out that the company is willing to pay for the room - sometimes the Saturday flight is so much cheaper than the Sunday one that the company saves money by putting you up for an extra night.  **Either way, the company doesn't lose, but the employee may be able to get something they wouldn't normally be able to afford**

Comment: @ChrisH I didn't challenge you specifically? it was rhetorical, you responded to it so I played along. :)

Comment: @NotStandingwithGoGotaHome your first comment today, addressed to me, is what seemed to be the "challenge". BTW, this is more common on long-haul. And for someone like me, who tries not to fly, if I'm flying on business I may well make the most of being somewhere I wouldn't otherwise be

Comment: @ChrisH Ah yes, my friends do that too.

Answer (score 8):

> Got a new Job as manager in a startup company.

Congrats!

> They invited me to do the onboard training in their HQ which is in Paris.

Fancy!

> I have to stay for 7 working days.

Exciting!

> Should I expect them to give me extra money for the days? Apart from the hotel and travel expenses?

What other expenses are you incurring?

If you had to make extensive/expensive babysitting arrangements for your child then I would certainly bring that hardship to light. I think it would be rather rude if the company simply expects that a parent automagically has the support infrastructure to have their child supervised for free for 7 days.

If you expect them to cover your tourism expenses then that's a bit of an overreach on your part. During your training, see how many people you can rub elbows with who have the company card and try to get invited to a night out on the town.

Answer (score 5):

Since the company is based in France, the short answer is that you should expect meals to be covered together with the hotel and travel expenses. It wouldn't be odd at all to ask about that. Some of the meals might be provided as part of the onboarding or possibly in the cantine (if there is one, which is not generally the case at startups), otherwise you should be able to expense them.

Incidentally, since the tax office (technically: Urssaf) allows paying up to €19.40 each for lunch and dinner with minimal formalities and no taxes, many employers will simply offer to pay that as a matter of course, no matter how much you actually spent. If you want more, you need expense the meal following whatever process your employer put in place and their accounting department will require receipts. These rules do not necessarily apply to you as you presumably do not have a French work contract but this should give you an idea of what travel policies tend to be like in France.

If you were based in France, you would not be entitled to time off or any compensation for the fact that you are not able to go back home every night so unless there is a specific legal obligation to do so (e.g. through a collective bargaining agreement), I wouldn't expect your employer to give you anything beyond transportation, meals, and lodging.

Answer (score 0):

One of my previous employers had a simple rule for this:

- If you stay abroad for three months or less, you need to fill in expense notes.
- If you stay abroad for more than three months, you get a living allowance.

The difference?

Well, expense notes mean that whatever you spend abroad and what is accepted by your company (staying at a hotel, car rent, parking expenses, toll, taxi, meals, ...) must be kept and declared once you return (make sure to keep your receipts).
Living allowance means that you don't need to bother doing all that administration: you get a certain amount of money and you can use this during your stay. If you consume less, you might make profit. If you consume more, that's totally up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The normal thing to happen is:

1. You get paid your salary as if you were working. Seven working days probably means you arrive Sunday, and leave Wednesday, going to work as normal on Thursday, and your job starts on the first day of training. I'd expect them to pay for the hotel if you decide to arrive on Saturday. They *should* pay your salary for Sunday, but with a monthly salary this may be included as part of your salary.
2. You fill in expenses for your travel cost, for your hotel room, and most likely there is a standard allowance for food and cost. Be very carefully to keep all the receipt.

All this should be agreed before you leave. And take the opportunity to enjoy being in Paris.